# Clarification needed for this transformation problem:

Tags: complex-analysis

I was preparing for an old entrance exam question paper and was stuck on the following problem:

> Under the transformation $w=\sqrt \frac {1-iz}{z-i}$ ,the region $D=\{z\in \Bbb C:|z|<1 \}$ is transformed to which of the following?
>
> 1. $\{z \in \Bbb C: 0 <\arg z <\pi\}$
> 2. $\{z \in \Bbb C: -\pi <\arg z <\pi\}$
> 3. $\{z \in \Bbb C: \pi/2 <\arg z <\pi \,\,\text{or}\,\, 3\pi/2<\arg z<2\pi \}$
> 4. $\{z \in \Bbb C: 0 <\arg z <\pi/2 \,\,\text{or}\,\, \pi<\arg z<3\pi/2 \}$

$\color {green} {\text{I was trying to express}\,\, z \,\,\text{in terms of}\,\, w\,\, \text {and then use the condition}\,\, |z|<1}\,$ but things get complicated in my calculation.

Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: $w^2$ is perhaps easier to work with. Also, try a few easy-to-work-with points, like $\pm i$, $\pm 1$ and $0$.

Comment: Unfortunately,I do not have the answer key to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should proceed as below:

Let $$u=\frac{z+i}{z-i}$$ Then you have $$w^2=-iu$$ Now, if $u=x+iy,\ x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, then using $|z|<1$ and $$z=i\frac{u+1}{u-1}$$ you get the conditions $$x<0$$i.e. the transformation from $z$ to $u$ maps the interior of the unit circle to the left half plane of $\mathbb{C}$.

Then, the transformation $iu$ rotates the left-half plane by $+90^{\circ}$ in the anti-clockwise direction, giving the lower half plane of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $\{Im(z)<0,\quad z\in \mathbb{C}\}$ and then the negation of that gives you the upper half plane of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $$w^2\in \{z\in \mathbb{C}\big|Im(z)>0\}$$ Then, if $w=a+ib$, we have $$a^2-b^2\in \mathbb{R},\quad ab>0$$This region is the option $4$.

Comment: If option $3$ is correct then either the real or the imaginary part is going to be negative right, which makes $uv<0$. If my derivation is correct in the answer, then $uv>0$ should happen. That's why I am opting for option $4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Samrat. Now,it is clear to me.

Comment: Welcome! @learner.